# How do I get out of ajax infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, video-player

I started a video project. I wrote my video player myself. I'm using javascript, jquery, asp.net and c #.

I made the video stop in seconds that the user set and the user asked questions to come to the screen. The video stops. The question is coming. Clicking an answer option. The clicked option is saved in the database (for analysis).

I send my data to the server side via ajax. It works perfectly when you answer questions instantly. But I wait for a certain amount of time I click the button, I can't skip the question. The question does not go from the screen as if it entered an infinite loop. I bring my questions to the screen with the css I created with Z-index.

I tried "cache: false" in ajax. But it didn't. Chrome, Edge and Android waiting for a certain period of time I encounter this problem. But when the first question comes up on the screen in Ios and Safari, the question is stuck if I don't wait for a certain time ...

The following is the ajax code that runs when the first option is clicked.

I'd appreciate it if you helped. I've been dealing with this problem for about two weeks.

```
c1.onclick=function(){

    $.ajax({

            type:"POST",
            url: "VideoPlayerDemo.aspx/SonucKaydet", 
            data:'{user:'+JSON.stringfy(user)+',VKodu:'+JSON.stringfy(VKodu)+',SoruKodu:'+JSON.stringfy(user)+'}',
            contenttype:"json",
            success:function(data){
                if(document.getElementById("my_ad").style.visibility !="hidden")
                {
                    document.getElementById("my_ad").style.visibility ="hidden"; 
                }   
            },   
        }),   
    }),
    v.play();
};
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Unfortunately,absent error...

Comment: Can you see the network call being made?

Comment: My function goes into ajax. I know because if I clicked on the database 1000 times, it saves it smoothly. I also checked in success with Alert. Ajax-web service enters an infinite loop between function-and global.asax (begin request function).

Comment: If the problem is in the database or not, I use the following function to trigger the check. ----------> v.addEventListener ('playing', function () {setInterval (catch_the_frame, 10);}, false);

Comment: Can you try to move v.play(); line in the success function?

Comment: ı tried already,but it is dont play().

Comment: It works seamlessly in instant clicks. When you stop and wait for a while, it looks like it's locked up.

Comment: What happens when you remove the ajax code? I think still it will stack again. Also add a log code c1.onclick function. Your player could call that method in a loop.

Comment: How do I switch to the server side if I remove my ajax code? Ajax is not necessary for the questions to come, but it is essential for me to keep the results when I click the button. Is there an option other than Ajax?

Comment: I mean, you should check if the problem is with onclick or ajax. try this, c1.onclick=function(){v.play();}; I think your problem is irrelevant the ajax code. If this code works fine, make your ajax call synchronous. Add async: true

Comment: I did it the way you said. When it stops for a while, it becomes the same. I clicked on the screen does not go. the question does not pass when I wait.

Comment: the problem is, as you say, onclick. but what?